# oracle excpetion while inserting from one table to another table= single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, .net, oracle

i am inserting values from table `A` to table `B` with following query .Now i am getting an error like `single-row subquery returns more than one row`.If i remove two fields `ACCESS_ACNT`,`IDV` ,then i can insert, otherwise with full query i am getting the error.
Full query is  as below

```
INSERT
INTO B
  (
    T_NAME,
    IP,
    LOCATION,
    ACCESS_ACNT,
    SERVICE,
    IDV
  )
SELECT T_NAME,
  IP,
  LOCATION,
  ACCESS_ACNT,
  SERVICE,
  IDV
FROM A ;
```

successfull query after removing ACCESS_ACNT, IDV is as below

```
 INSERT
INTO B
  (
    T_NAME,
    IP,
    LOCATION,
    SERVICE
  )
SELECT T_NAME,
  IP,
  LOCATION,
  SERVICE
FROM A ;
```

.How to fix this issue

Comment: Your query has no subquery.  The error is most likely caused by a trigger, so you would have to investigate that code.

Comment: i dont think so,How to know which trigger?This was working fine at beggining .but now all of us sudden

Comment: Try  running `select * from all_triggers where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'`

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing the problematic fields data types, look for any constraints on B, try also adding the table name prefix for your select - a.idv etc.

Comment: All did ,but no luck till now